# how to draw an waveform using pcm file(.pcm) in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, waveform, wavesurfer.js

Do I convert pcm to mp3?
I do test using wavesurfer.js to draw an waveform using mp3 and it's done. But I don't know how to use pcm. Here is code.

```
//javascript
    var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
    container: '#waveform',
    scrollParent: true,
    waveColor: 'violet',
    progressColor: 'purple'
});

wavesurfer.load('/audio/1.mp3'); // I want to use .pcm insted of .mp3

wavesurfer.on('ready', function () {
    wavesurfer.play();
});

// html
  <div id="waveform">waveform</div>
  <button onclick="wavesurfer.play()">Play</button>
  <button onclick="wavesurfer.pause()">Pause</button>
  <button onclick="wavesurfer.stop()">Stop</button>
  <button onclick="wavesurfer.playPause()">Play/Pause</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone landing here from Google:

Once your file is loaded (inside the `wavesurfer.on('ready'..` function) you can call the `wavesurfer.exportPCM()`, something like this:

```
wavesurfer.on('ready', () => {
     wavesurfer.exportPCM().then(PCMData => {
          console.log(PCMData);
     });
});
```

In the log you will get that data. Once you get that data you can save it on your server, and the next time your page loads, you can pass it as the second argument to your `wavesufer.load(url, PCMData)`, and you will immediately see the waveform.